# Which extension would you recommend for my Multivendor solution?

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-vendor

**I want to setup my site to act as a multivendor/multi warehouse ecommerce site.**

In my business model, I don't have stock but the **stock is owned by the local shops and distributors**. The process flow should work as follows:

- Customer orders **product A which is owned by vendor 10**. Payment is done via a credit card but before payment is taken product has to be verified if it is in stock. An email with the order should be automatically send as soon when the order was made.
- In other words each product should be assigned to a vendor or warehouse and mailing address.
- **On confirmation of the order in stock**, (how can this be manage?) the payment can be processed.Now invoice can be send to customer and **Vendor 10** which should also be attached to the shipped **product A**.
- At the same time the shipping company should receive the order for them to collect at Vendor 10.
- The same process should be followed when **product B is owned by Vendor 13** for example. It might be possible to do this with a multi warehouse setup?

Is there someone here who has experience with a similar setup and is there a low cost solution to get this in a nice way done?

Comment: You can try this: http://www.magextended.com/dropship.html - it adds vendor field to products attributes, has vendor login with stock/orders management, etc.

Comment: Please check multi vendor marketplace solution http://marketplace.webkul.com/

Comment: Check out the multivendor solution - http://cedcommerce.com/magento-extensions/marketplace

Answer (score 1):

I have used uDropShip (www.unirgy.com) for a similar setup. It includes a separate admin panel for vendors to update inventory counts, which are then reflected in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I understood. For your business model, stand alone [multi merchant eCommerce platform](http://www.laravelecommerce.com/multi-vendor-shopping-cart-software/) will be pretty good for operating ecommerce business with different vendor. Only thing, you need to set up delivery process from warehouse to customer. Am using laravel ecommerce for my business which is simple and quite similar to Big commerce.

Comment: This is a laravel extension and has nothing to do with magento, or I'm wrong?